# flutter error of not passing parameter value, (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: [](0))

Tags: flutter, dart

I have project in flutter and there I have getjson.json file I want to  make list of it and pass to class as parameter, but inside that class I can't receive that data as list in my quiz class. I want to display first question as mydata[0][i.toString()], and it's giving error The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: )
here is getjson code:

```
    class getJson extends StatelessWidget {
  const getJson({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/quiz.json"),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("there is an error");
        }
        // if (snapshot == null) {
        //   return Scaffold(
        //     body: const Center(
        //       child: Text("List is empty.."),
        //     ),
        //   );
        // } else
        List? myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        if (myData == null) {
          // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
          return Scaffold(
            body: const Center(
              child: Text("Loading.."),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          // return Text("Data is $myData[0]");
          return quiz(myData: myData, marks: 0, vie: 0, level: 0, uid: "0");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is quiz code:

```
class quiz extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var mydata;
  int marks;
  int vie;
  int level;
  quiz(
      {Key? key,
      this.mydata,
      required this.marks,
      required this.vie,
      required this.level,
      required this.uid,
      required List myData})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  State<quiz> createState() => _quizState(mydata, marks, vie, level, uid);
}

and my quiz class is 

    

class _quizState extends State<quiz> {
  String message = "score" + " 0 " + "-" + "Best" + " 0 ";
  String levels = "Level: " + "0" + "/21";
  String vies = "5";
  final String uid;
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var mydata;
  int marks = 0;
  int vie = 5;
  int level = 0;
  _quizState(this.mydata, this.marks, this.vie, this.level, this.uid);

  Color ch = Colors.indigo;
  Color rig = Colors.green;
  Color wro = Colors.red;

  int i = 1;
  int timer = 30;
  int click = 20;
  String showTimer = "30";

  Map<String, Color> buttoncolor = {
    'a': Colors.indigoAccent,
    'b': Colors.indigoAccent,
    'c': Colors.indigoAccent,
    'd': Colors.indigoAccent,
  };
  bool cancelTimer = false;
  int g = 0;

  void startTimer() async {
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        if (timer < 1) {
          t.cancel();
          nextQuestion();
        } else if (cancelTimer == true) {
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          timer = timer - 1;
        }
        showTimer = timer.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    click = 20;
    cancelTimer = false;
    timer = 30;
    setState(() {
      if (i < 20) {
        level++;
        levels = 'level: ' + "$level" + "/20";
        i++;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => result(marks: marks)));
      }
      buttoncolor["a"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      buttoncolor["b"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      buttoncolor["c"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
      buttoncolor["d"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
    });
    startTimer();
  }

  void quit() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => result(marks: marks)));
  }

  void checkAnswer(String k) async {
    if (click == 20) {
      if (mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()][k]) {
        marks = marks + 5;
        message = "Score" + "$marks" + "-" + "Best" + g.toString();
        ch = rig;
      } else {
        ch = wro;
        vie = vie - 1;
        vies = "$vie";
      }
      setState(() {
        buttoncolor[k] = ch;
        if (k != "a" &&
            mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()]['a']) {
          buttoncolor["a"] = rig;
        }
        if (k != "b" &&
            mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()]['b']) {
          buttoncolor["b"] = rig;
        }
        if (k != "c" &&
            mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()]['c']) {
          buttoncolor["c"] = rig;
        }
        if (k != "d" &&
            mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()]['c']) {
          buttoncolor["c"] = rig;
        }
        cancelTimer = true;
      });
      click = 30;
      if (vie > 0) {
        Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), nextQuestion);
      } else {
        Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), quit);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget choiicebutton(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 0.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () => {checkAnswer(k)},
        child: Text(
          mydata[1][i.toString()][k],
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
        color: buttoncolor[k],
        splashColor: Colors.indigo[700],
        highlightColor: Colors.indigo[700],
        minWidth: 400.0,
        height: 45.0,
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => accueil()));
          },
        ),
        title: Text("ART QUICK QUIZ"),
        actions: [
          Text(
            vies,
            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
            style: TextStyle(
                height: 2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        toolbarHeight: 50.0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Scrollbar(
          child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1),
          color: Colors.indigoAccent,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.indigo.shade100, Colors.indigo.shade200],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    width: 180,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      message,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    width: 160,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      levels,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  mydata[0][i.toString()],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    choiicebutton("a"),
                    choiicebutton("b"),
                    choiicebutton("c"),
                    choiicebutton("d"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                height: 120,
                width: 120.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                  boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[8],
                ),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  showTimer,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
                  ),
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, the problem was with name of parameter passing to quiz, it was supposed to the same as decleared  in quiz.